# Tensorflow neural network image prediction

Tags: networking, tensorflow, predict

I want to figure it out how to solve a basic tensorflow problem. I want to be able to design and train a model that should be able to differentiate between me and my family members. So, I have around 100 labeled images for each family member. (1 is me, 2 is my bother and so on)

After the training, if I provide a different image to the model, I want to predict if the person from that picture is a family member or not (EG: a result of 1 should point out that the person in the fed image is me, "2" is my brother and so on). I don't know how to approach the problem. I started creating a feed forward neural network with 3 hidden layers (100 neurons each). As input, I feed into the NN images in batches of 10 pieces. 
The input layer consists of a 73984 (because my images are 272x27x grayscaled pictures). The activation function for each layer is reLU, the learning rate is 0.001 and the output layer is the "y" variable from below.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 73984)) #input
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1)) #output
```

All the images are labeled and loaded into the system and fed into the NN.

Is this a good approach? I`m not sure that I`ve chosen the correct number of output neurons since more than one person is involved in the result.
Also, If I run 10 epoch of training, the cost is quite unclear too (because it varies from one epoch to another):

```
Epoch: 1 cost = 1704869.83786
Epoch: 2 cost = 122763.82891
Epoch: 3 cost = 179394.59451
Epoch: 4 cost = 562933.02995
Epoch: 5 cost = 496258.06337
Epoch: 6 cost = 109202.11328
Epoch: 7 cost = 107059.53917
Epoch: 8 cost = 34747.37408
Epoch: 9 cost = 95627.10324
Epoch: 10 cost = 122551.38151
```

When I try to predict the accuracy using a test image this is how I do it:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("accuracy: %r" % sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_x, y: test_y}))
```

but there seems to be a problem because every time a value of 1.0 is shown. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: I know the input data is really low (the number of images) and I know that convolutional NN is a better approach to this, but just for the sake of learning, I`ve chosen this method.

Comment: you are on the right path but confused with how many neurons to use in the output layer(softmax layer). It should be how many members in your family.So the layer should be `y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, number_of_family_members)) #output`

Comment: Added to that make sure, your targets is a one-hot vector (number_of_family_members,)

Comment: Thank you for you answer! If I use a one-hot vector, what happens when you feed a different person's image in the NN? By different I mean a person that is not in my family? How does the network classify it?

Comment: For that we need to think out of box, add that unknown in your training dataset and add another neuron in the output layer. One hot vector now will be (number_of_family_members+1,) . Softmax output layer serves  multi-class predictions